# Using maxrecursion in INSERT query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, insert, common-table-expression, recursive-query

Thank you for looking at this.

I have two CTE tables that generate duty times, the calculations are convoluted so wont bother you with them.

Here is the SQL (Simplified)

```
DECLARE @StartDate Datetime -- Start Date for the Duties to be generated
DECLARE @PatternStartPoint int --Start Point in Pattern eg 3 - 
DECLARE @PatternSize int --The length of the shift pattern
DECLARE @User int 
SET @User = 1111;
SET @PatternSize = 3;
SET @DaysRequired=16; --Testing assume 16
SET @StartDate = DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE())); --for testing use today
SET @PatternStartPoint =3;


--Get Job Duty Pattern
WITH Pattern (P_DayNumber, P_DayType, P_Start, P_End)
AS
(
Select              D_DayNumber,D_Type,D_Start,D_End
from                dbo.Tbl_Jobs as J
join                dbo.Tbl_Patterns as P
on                  J.J_PatternID = P.Pattern_ID
join                dbo.Tbl_PatternDetails as D
on                  P.Pattern_ID=d.D_Pattern_ID
)
,
--Get DateList
Datelist (MyDate, DayNumber) AS 
(
    SELECT @StartDate AS MyDate, @PatternStartPoint as DayNumber
    UNION ALL
    Select MyDate + 1,  (DayNumber+1) - (CAST((Daynumber+1)/(@PatternSize+.01) as int)*@PatternSize) --% (@PatternSize)
    FROM Datelist
    WHERE MyDate < (@Startdate + @DaysRequired)-1

) 

INSERT INTO [IDAHO].[dbo].[Appointments]
           ([Subject]
           ,[Description]
           ,[Start]
           ,[End]
           ,[RoomID]
           ,[UserID]
           )
            (    
            SELECT  
                'Standard Work Pattern'     
                ,'IDAHO Generated on ' + CONVERT(nvarchar(20),getdate())
                ,mydate + p.P_Start
                ,mydate + p.P_End
                ,1
                ,@User as A_User
            FROM            Datelist as d
            join            Pattern as p
            on          p.P_DayNumber=d.DayNumber
            Where           mydate + p.P_Start is not null
            OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)

            )
```

I am getting an error with the MAXRECURSION line, if I remove the line and try to generate more than 100 'Duties' it errors (being the default value).

If I Change the last statement to a simple select it seems to work??? as shown below

```
DECLARE @StartDate Datetime -- Start Date for the Duties to be generated
DECLARE @PatternStartPoint int --Start Point in Pattern eg 3 -
DECLARE @PatternSize int --The length of the shift pattern
DECLARE @DaysRequired int --The length of the shift pattern
DECLARE @User int
SET @User=1111;
SET @PatternSize = 3;
SET @DaysRequired=160; --Testing assume 16
SET @StartDate = DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE())); --for testing use today
SET @PatternStartPoint =3;


--Get Job Duty Pattern
WITH Pattern (P_DayNumber, P_DayType, P_Start, P_End)
AS
(
Select              D_DayNumber,D_Type,D_Start,D_End
from                dbo.Tbl_Jobs as J
join                dbo.Tbl_Patterns as P
on                  J.J_PatternID = P.Pattern_ID
join                dbo.Tbl_PatternDetails as D
on                  P.Pattern_ID=d.D_Pattern_ID
)
,
--Get DateList
Datelist (MyDate, DayNumber) AS 
(
    SELECT @StartDate AS MyDate, @PatternStartPoint as DayNumber
    UNION ALL
    Select MyDate + 1,  (DayNumber+1) - (CAST((Daynumber+1)/(@PatternSize+.01) as int)*@PatternSize) --% (@PatternSize)
    FROM Datelist
    WHERE MyDate < (@Startdate + @DaysRequired)-1

) 

            SELECT  
                            'Standard Work Pattern'     
                            ,'IDAHO Generated on ' + CONVERT(nvarchar(20),getdate())
                            ,mydate + p.P_Start
                            ,mydate + p.P_End
                            ,1
                            ,@User as A_User
            FROM            Datelist as d
            join            Pattern as p
            on              p.P_DayNumber=d.DayNumber
            Where           mydate + p.P_Start is not null
            OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Have I put the command in the wrong place?
Why does it work with select but not insert?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think its because the CTE doesn't finally get assembled into a result set until the final select is run, which is why tour second query works. To make the insert work, try:

```
DECLARE @StartDate Datetime -- Start Date for the Duties to be generated
DECLARE @PatternStartPoint int --Start Point in Pattern eg 3 -
DECLARE @PatternSize int --The length of the shift pattern
DECLARE @DaysRequired int --The length of the shift pattern
DECLARE @User int
SET @User=1111;
SET @PatternSize = 3;
SET @DaysRequired=160; --Testing assume 16
SET @StartDate = DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE())); --for testing use today
SET @PatternStartPoint =3;


--Get Job Duty Pattern
INSERT INTO [IDAHO].[dbo].[Appointments]
           ([Subject]
           ,[Description]
           ,[Start]
           ,[End]
           ,[RoomID]
           ,[UserID]
           )
select *
from
(
    SELECT  
        'Standard Work Pattern'     [Subject]
        ,'IDAHO Generated on ' + CONVERT(nvarchar(20),getdate()) [Description]
        ,mydate + p.P_Start [Start]
        ,mydate + p.P_End [End]
        ,1 [RoomID]
        ,@User [UserID]
    FROM            
    (
        SELECT @StartDate AS MyDate, @PatternStartPoint as DayNumber
        UNION ALL
        Select MyDate + 1,  (DayNumber+1) - (CAST((Daynumber+1)/(@PatternSize+.01) as int)*@PatternSize) --% (@PatternSize)
        FROM Datelist
        WHERE MyDate < (@Startdate + @DaysRequired)-1
    ) as d
    join
    (
        Select D_DayNumber,D_Type,D_Start,D_End
        from                dbo.Tbl_Jobs as J
        join                dbo.Tbl_Patterns as P
        on                  J.J_PatternID = P.Pattern_ID
        join                dbo.Tbl_PatternDetails as D
        on                  P.Pattern_ID=d.D_Pattern_ID
    ) as p
    on              p.P_DayNumber=d.DayNumber
    Where           mydate + p.P_Start is not null
) x;
```

That might work.

(Expanded as requested)
(Amended to remove CTEs)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am a bit of a newby at SQL, could you please expand on the answer, not sure exactly what I need to type in...

Comment: Expanded as requested

Comment: Thanks again but getting an error,
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WITH'.

Comment: Any clue what it is? OK - got your comment now

Comment: What happens if you take out the OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)?

Comment: Makes no difference if I remove the option. The error is on the line

Comment: WITH Pattern (P_DayNumber, P_DayType, P_Start, P_End)

Comment: CTE's removed. Try that

Comment: Hold on a minute - OK, try it now

Comment: Getting Invalid Object 'Datelist'

Comment: I've done a copy/paste error. Recast the query without CTE's as I've tried to do above. I can't validate it as I've not got your tables....

Comment: Can I send the tables to you? I think the error is because there isn't a CTE called Datelist now?

Comment: I'm afraid you can't. Did you write the original queries yourself? Why did you use CTEs?

Comment: lol, I have no idea, I just found an article on them and thought they would be most efficient. I couldn't think of another way to create a temp table that would give me a list of dates, like the 'Datelist' CTE

Comment: Is there a table called DateList?

Comment: that was originally a CTE as shown in original question. I do appreciate your help Simon

Comment: Can you rewrite the CTE DateList as a standard query?

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help I rewrote the CTE as a temp table and my problem is solved, Thanks for the help